# How To Find Division Without Using Division Operator In Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, division

I've Found How to do it for normal numbers which gives quotient above 1

How to find value for which we will get quotient below 1

For example if 28 divided by 500 it gives 0.056

How to implement above example without using division operator

Comment: How about `28*500**-1`

Comment: what's wrong with using the division operator? Is this some kind of weird trivia question? (Nothing wrong with that if so, I can enjoy fun challenges too. Just trying to understand the reason for the question.)

Comment: If you're asking how to do division without using the division operator, the question makes no sense.

Comment: Sunil, it sounds like an interesting challenge, but it's unclear what you need to do. You can help others help you by explaining more about it what you're trying to do, and show the work you have done so far.

Comment: Thanks wim that's what exactly i'm trying to do. Robin Zigmond... It's Kind of fun challange. Robert Dodler... Check wim's comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a way to do this, unless you count reciprocals. However, these are fractions which means they use divide.

For example:

```
>>> 30 / 5 # original calculation
6
>>> 30 * 0.2 # using the reciprocal of 5 – but no division sign visible!
6
```

However, this option clearly uses division. If you don't see it, here's how:

```
def divide(x, y):
    return x * (1/y)
```

Because to make a number a reciprocal, you have to divide. But take into consideration that every whole number uses divide: `5 = 5/1`, so it's just the same with a different denominator...

Comment: It's not so obvious that to make a reciprocal you need to divide. Suppose you have some nice exponentiation algorithm and you have 2 and already know from a calculation or table lookup what ln(2) is. Then you raise e to the -ln 2, and get 0.2.

Answer (score 0):

```
#in this case 18/2
e=18
t=2

o=0
l=t
count=0
t=0
for i in range(0,e):
  t+=l
  count+=1
  if t==e:
    o=1
    print(count)
    break
  if (t+l) > e:
    break
if o!=1:
  c=e-t
  print(count,'reminder of',c)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Comment: Outputs the wrong result when negative result is expected.

Answer (score 0):

You indicate you already have something without division that handles cases with quotients greater than 1. If so, you can reduce your as yet unsolved case like 28/500 by doing 2800/500 and then getting around dividing by 100 (at least directly) by adding two decimal places. Since you want two significant figures, it seems, you actually would want to do 28000/500, at least if you did things as I am guessing you did.
Here's how that plays out in code:

```
def algorithm_you_already_have(a, b):
    """I assume a>b>0 you can add logic to handle negatives or check for b == 0
    you say you already have something that works if a divided by b is greater than 1
    Here is one thing you might have done, repeated subtraction"""
    assert a > b # this was only working and for use when quotient was greater than 1, you said
    assert b > 0 # cannot divide by 0, and not dealing with negatives here, could higher up
    result = 0
    while a >= b:
        a -= b
        result += 1
    if a + a >= b: # round up if remainder is at least half of divisor
        result += 1
    return result

# assumes positives, you can add cases as needed
def algorithm_you_need(a, b):
    assert a > 0
    assert b > 0
    temp_result = 0
    if a == b:
        return 1
    if a > b:
        return algorithm_you_already_have(a, b)
    # still here, then a < b, which is the new case you need
    places_shifted = 0
    while a < b:
        a *= 10
        places_shifted += 1
    if a == b:
        temp_result = 1
    else:
        temp_result = algorithm_you_already_have(10 * a, b) # times 10 to get a second figure as desired
        # but do not count is as a shift, because you are putting the next figure, if any, beyond the first
    # process as string
    temp_result = str(temp_result)
    while places_shifted > 1:
        temp_result = '0' + temp_result
        places_shifted -= 1
    temp_result ="0." + temp_result
    return float(temp_result)

print(algorithm_you_need(28,500))
```

Comment: now that I look at it, it might be neater to tack on an E-3 or similar